# laravel 7 including external class

Tags: php, class, laravel-7

I'm trying to include an external class to use API but I'm getting this error:

> Class 'App\Services\VedicRishiClient' not found

at `$vedicRishi = new VedicRishiClient($userId, $apiKey);`

I followed this https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/ tutorial.

Not sure what to do?

This is my PagesController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Profilecard;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use App\Services\VedicRishiClient;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    // instantiate VedicRishiClient class
    $vedicRishi = new VedicRishiClient($userId, $apiKey);

    $responseData = $vedicRishi->call($resourceName,$data);

    return $responseData;

    return view('pages.index')->with('location', $location);
}
```

This is the additional Class I'm trying to include:

```
<?php

class VedicRishiClient
{
private $userId = null;
private $apiKey = null;
private $apiEndPoint = "http://api.vedicrishiastro.com/v1";

/**
 * @param $uid userId for Vedic Rishi Astro API
 * @param $key api key for Vedic Rishi Astro API access
 */
public function __construct($uid, $key)
{
    $this->userId = $uid;
    $this->apiKey = $key;
}

private function getCurlReponse($resource, array $data)
{
    $serviceUrl = $this->apiEndPoint.$resource;
    $authData = $this->userId.":".$this->apiKey;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $serviceUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $header[] = 'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($authData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

public function call($resourceName, $data)
{
    $resData = $this->getCurlReponse($resourceName, $data);

    return $resData;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should read the tutorial more carefully. Especially the part about how to include external classes in a controller.

Comment: Your class is missing the proper `namespace` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the

VedicRishiClient

Class is found.

Clearly it is not at App\Services\VedicRishiClient where it is looking. By default it will look in the current files namespace (look to the top of the php file).

If VedicRishiClient is accessed directly, then try

```
$vedicRishi = new \VedicRishiClient($userId, $apiKey);
```

Instead, or add

```
use VedicRishiClient;
```

To the top of your script